# configure and publish data to NifiKafkaConsumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, kafka-consumer-api

I have my kafka producer nd consumer written on my local in eclipse.
Now I have started nifi on my local and want to use kafkaConsumer on NIFI
below is the pic of the configuration.

1. I now want to run producer on the eclipse and see the data queued up in my consumer on NIFI UI. I have configured it properly as required but when I run my producer on eclipse the data doesn't show up  ON the NIFI kafkaConsumer process. but when I run consumer from my eclipse the data publish to the topic is being read . can someone guide or help me with the same?

kafka brokers run on localhost:9092

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the consumer configs in NiFi and your custom consumer in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, Somewhat @mazaneicha , I want to know when I am writing my Java Custom nifi Processor to get data from kafkaConsumer , the data will come in form of sessions ? so that means my onTrigger() function is the entry point of data from consumer into my java program where I might wanna refine the data little more and then after some data cleansing , might wanna put it to some Database.

Comment: @Lalit Thanks for the input lalit I was able to solve the issue by giving it a connection to putFile on the NIFI UI.  I want to know something about sessions in NIFI where I can read the Kafka messages from the consumer.

Comment: @aditya-verma That sounds like a totally different question...

Comment: Yes, I mean from your link I was able to figure it out , But my next hurdle is how does the nifi customer processor reads data from outside. If you can help me with that, that would be awesome.@mazaneicha